# Fetch Google Reviews and reply them using API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-places-api, google-my-business-api

I would like to get reviews of any businesses which i have got by using https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=YOUR_PLACE_ID. But I would also like to reply them using an api. I didn't found any source on this. I would appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: You can get up to 5 reviews in place details. There is no any endpoint to get all reviews and reply them.